# How can I chain HTTP calls with the next URL in the reponse body of the previous HTTP call?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So my problem is that I need to request a big amount of measurements. And the API I'm using only returns a maximum of 2000 objects, with the url for the next objects in the body of the response.

This might be a bit confusing, so here an example of my first request:

```
getMeasurements(id: string, dateTo: string) {
  return this.http.get(`${API}/measurements?id=${id}&dateTo=${dateTo}&pageSize=2000`)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let body = response.json();
            // here I return an array containing 2000 objects
            return body.measurements;
        })
}
```

However, the body object here also contains a property 'next', which has the url for the next 2000 objects.

So how do I get the next request:

```
this.http.get(body.next)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    let body = response.json();
    return body.measurements;
  })
```

chained with the first request. And considering there could be another 'next' url in the next request body, how do I make this dynamic?

Comment: What is the termination condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use expand:

```
getMeasurements(id: string, dateFrom: Date, dateTo: Date) {
    const get = (url: string, measurements?: any[]) => this.http.get(url).map((response: Response) => response.json());

    return get(`${API}/measurements?source=${id}&dateFrom=${dateFrom}&dateTo=${dateTo}`, [])
        .expand(body => {
            return body.next ? get(body.next) : Observable.empty()
        })
        .map(body => body.measurements);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a logic how to do it

1st create a function where you do request

```js
function a(url) {
  this.http.get(url)
    .map((response: Response) => {
      let body = response.json();

      if (body.next != "") {
        a(body.next);
      }
      // here use your an array containing 2000 objects
    })
}
// Call Your function
a('${API}/measurements?id=${id}&dateTo=${dateTo}&pageSize=2000');
```

Comment: I don't think this would concatenate the results. You don't return an Observable so the first request won't want for the second. So the result of the second request would go lost no?

Comment: Well if you want to create a function which gives dynamic result than you have to create a sync request and keep looping till body.next is null and than give result.

Comment: Please study the [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
getMeasurements(id: string, dateTo: string) {
  const get = (url: string) => this.http.get(url).map(response => {
    const body = response.json();
    const nextUrl = body.next;

    return nextUrl
      ? Observable.of(body.measurements).concat(get(nextUrl))
      : Observable.of(body.measurements);
  });

  return get(`${API}/measurements?id=${id}&dateTo=${dateTo}&pageSize=2000`)
    .mergeAll();
}
```

Note I have not tested this.

Comment: I think this goes in the right direction. However, I just tested this, and my subscribe function is only called twice; first time with the first 2000 objects, the second time I get an Observable back...

Comment: interesting. I will need to play with it.